# помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: python, telegram-bot

я только начинаю заниматься телеграмм ботами, нужен совет, правильно ли я сделал, если нет, пожалуйста скажите как исправить, просто уже не знаю что делать. Мне не понятно почему, когда я запускаю бота и присылаю ему сообщение "Привет" он через 1 минуту мне ничего не присылает, хотя для парсинга у меня даже отрыт браузер для того, чтобы парсер смог работать P.S: токен бота я сделал в отдельном файле, который называется конфиг, в начале я его импортировал.

```
import telebot
import config
import schedule
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def get_text_message(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        def job():
            url = "https://currency.com/ru/btc-to-usd?utm_course=rbc&utm_campaign=quote"
            response = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
            main = soup.find("strong", class_ = 'table-instruments__price')
            print(main.text)
        schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

я хочу сделать так, чтобы когда я запускал этот файл и писал телеграмм боту "Привет", начинал работать парсер и бот мне отвечал

Answer (score 0):

Когда создаешь телеграмм ботов, дискорд ботов и так далее, ты работаешь с асинхронными функциями(работают независимо друг от друга). Модули `time` и `schedule` можно только использовать не в асинхронных функциях, ибо, фактически, с помощью этих модулей ты останавливаешь **всю** программу, а не только время для одной функции(а в этом случае команды). Для реализации программы придётся изучить документацию [aiocron](https://pypi.org/project/aiocron/) для планирования задач (а в этом случае каждую минуту). Модули `time` И `schedule` надо обязательно убирать.

К сожалению, не я не очень знаком с библиотекой телеграмм бота, поэтому здесь я помочь не очень сильно могу. Я бы сделал так: человек отправлял бы команду, бот бы записывал id человека в базу данных, а потом уже с помощью отдельной функции, запланированной на каждую минуту, можно было бы всем отправлять данные всем подписавшимся. (Так как бот будет хоститься на Heroku, то и там же можно будет подключить базу данных)Надеюсь, что помог!

Comment: а какую базу данных использовать, я просто с ними раньше не работал вообще

Comment: На heroku можно будет использовать Аддон ClearDB MySQL